# How to convert html source from an email body to valid html?

Tags: php, html, mime

I am using a php script to automatically download emails from an IMAP server. The HTML of the email body looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=3D"en" xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml=
ns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com=
:office:office"><head><meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/htm=
l; charset=3Dutf-8"><meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width=
,initial-scale=3D1"><meta http-equiv=3D"X-UA-Compatible" content=3D"IE=3Ded=
ge"><meta name=3D"x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"><meta name=3D"forma=
```

This looks all like proper html to me except the line break with the '=' at the end but I am not 100% sure if there are no other contents changed in the way html is stored in email.

What would be the best method to remove the '=' at the end of line where required and ohter potential changes that happen when storing html in an email body, ideally in PHP or linux command line? I want to eventually save this as an HTML file so that it can be looked at in a browser or converted from that format into others.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format used in emails is called "quoted printable". The php function to convert it is [quoted_printable_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php)

A sample function to solve this issue would be:

```
$decoded_data = quoted_printable_decode($text);
```

Comment: You may also need `utf8_encode` if there are Unicode characters.

Comment: @ouuan `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()` are deprecated. You should use `mb_convert_encoding()`. [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: @KHansen Would you like to edit the answer or post a new answer at [utf 8 - Php email body decoding to plain - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383339/php-email-body-decoding-to-plain)?

Comment: @ouuan I edited the accepted answer